# Use a variable name inside an Ansible lookup

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I'm using the AWS SSM lookup plugin to grab a value from SSM — but wanted to dynamically set the path to the SSM variable depending on the environment.

Hardcoding the environment works, so, I could write a task and use a `when:` condition for each possible environment, which feels a bit clunky.

```yaml
- name: Get CloudWatch Log Group Name from SSM for use in CloudWatch role
  set_fact:
    log_group_name: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/production/cloudwatch/log_group_name') }}"
```

I'm trying to do something like the below:

```yaml
- name: Get CloudWatch Log Group Name from SSM for use in CloudWatch role
  set_fact:
    log_group_name: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', environment + '/cloudwatch/log_group_name') }}"
```

But I get the following

> FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ lookup('aws_ssm', environment + '/cloudwatch/log_group_name') }}): can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"}

Are there other ways to use string formatting, such as:

```yaml
- name: Get CloudWatch Log Group Name from SSM for use in CloudWatch role
  set_fact:
    log_group_name: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '{}/cloudwatch/log_group_name'.format(Environment) }}"
```

Comment: What is not clear in "_can only concatenate list (not "str") to list_"? Your variable `environment` is a list and it cannot be concatenated with a string, obviously.

Comment: If you are sure that there is only one element in there, just do `environment | first ~ '/cloudwatch/log_group_name'`

Comment: Thank you - I noticed the name of the variable is reserved..

Comment: a good idea that you might see used here by other answerers is to prepend those variables with an underscore: `_environment`, so you are sure to not clash with an existing fact or variable.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to the usage of the `environment` variable - changed this to capital 'E' and everything works as expected:

```yaml
    - name: Get CloudWatch Log Group Name from SSM for use in CloudWatch role
      set_fact:
        log_group_name: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/' + Environment + '/cloudwatch/log_group_name') }}"
```

Comment: Make sure to update your question to let everyone know!